# Python Interpreter in Emacs repeats lines

Tags: python, emacs

What is happening:

```
>>> 2 * 10
2 * 10
20
>>>
```

What I want to happen:

```
>>> 2 * 10
20
>>>
```

Does anyone know why the command is printed out before being executed and how to stop it from doing that? I can't find any documentation about this. I'm using Emacs 23 on Mac OS X with Python 2.7.

Comment: How are you starting the Python process? `run-python`, `python-shell`?

Comment: Another way is to start `ansi-term` and then `ipython` inside it.

Comment: Well, I didn't know about ansi-term. I've been using M-x shell so thanks for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't use python, but I would guess that the python feature you are using has set the variable `comint-process-echoes` incorrectly.  Whatever the value in your buffer is, just reverse the boolean value.

Comint is a support library in Emacs for running inferior processes in Emacs.  It interacts with the prompts, and the python shell (or M-x shell) needs to be told about the echo feature.

In your shell buffer with the problem, do:

```
M-: (setq comint-process-echoes t)  ;; or nil
```

Comment: This works for me, too!  I wonder if you can help with [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830729/emacs-python-echoing-hooks-and-org-mode) which regards running this in a hook every time python starts up?

Comment: @Eric I am using Elpy on Emacs in ubuntu I do have the same problem but this solution is not working.Can help me out

Comment: I have found solution by setting the variable **elpy-shell-echo-input** to nil