# Emacs Python: Echoing, Hooks and Org-mode

Tags: python, emacs, hook, org-mode

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060609/python-interpreter-in-emacs-repeats-lines) I discovered how to fix the echoing problem in the python shell in emacs.  What I want to do is add this to my .emacs file so that it will happen automatically.

```lisp
(defun python-startup () 
  (setq comint-process-echoes t))

(add-hook 'py-shell-hook 'python-startup)
```

If I start a python shell (`M-x python-shell`), this hasn't worked.

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 22
22
22
```

I can run this function with `M-: (python-startup)`, and then the echoing behavior stops.

```
>>> 22
22
```

I don't know if I'm setting up the hook incorrectly, or if I should be using a different hook altogether.  As a side note, how do I know what hook is called for what function?  The end goal is to end up being able to use `:results output :session` in org-mode so that I can integrate python code without the results echoing every command.  I suspect that once I fix the hook, that is the behavior I will have, but I don't actually know if this is true.

Comment: In my version of Emacs (23.1.1) and Python 2.7.1, the shell echoes properly by default. When I set `comint-process-echoes` as you defined, the echoing behavior stops. I can't reproduce the duplicate echoing that you have above, so I suspect the bug exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

My brief investigation into this shows that `python-mode` (as found in my Emacs) has no `py-shell-hook`, so naturally it won't run anything you put in there.

When I looked at `python-mode`, there are no hooks that it runs, so you are a bit out of luck.

Your best bet it to just make your own command, for exmaple:

```
(defun alex-python-shell ()
  "Start a python shell my way."
  (interactive)
  (python-shell)
  (python-startup))
```

If you need to call `python-shell` interactively, use

```
(call-interactively 'python-shell)
```

Comment: Hmm, nice workaround for just starting up python myself.  I wonder though, is `python-mode` only for viewing .py files, and not for the shell?  If so, I wouldn't expect it to have a py-shell-hook or anything like that.  Nevertheless, do you know of some list of hooks somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I meant python-shell doesn't have any hooks.  Just do: M-x find-function RET python-shell RET and look for hooks being run in the code.  Easy-Breezy.