# Python Interpretor in Emacs, removing the input reprinting

Tags: emacs, python-3.x, interpreter

I am quite new to Emacs.

When running Emacs' python interpretor, it does

```
>>> print(24)
print(24)
24
```

Is there a way I can prevent the re-printing of my input and make it as below?

```
>>> print(24)
24
```

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick here is that the buffer you're running the python process in doesn't have `comint-process-echoes` set.

There are a couple of other questions that are relevant to your problem.

[How to turn off the echoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060609/python-interpreter-in-emacs-repeats-lines)

[How to set emacs so it always turns off echoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830729/emacs-python-echoing-hooks-and-org-mode)

But the basic gist is you need to customize the value of `comint-process-echoes`.  If you are new to emacs, you might not know that most customizations are done using emacs lisp, where setting a variable looks something like this:

```
(setq variable-name new-value)
```

In this case, the variable we want is `comint-process-echoes` so the lisp we want to evaluate is:

```
(setq comint-process-echoes t)
```

Where `t` is lisp-speak for "true."

So, to borrow the advice of the first link above, to actually tell emacs to evaluate this lisp code, use the `M-:` (meta+colon) command.  From the python shell buffer, type meta+colon, then type `(setq comint-process-echoes t)` then hit return.  Your problem should be solved.